# Outputting Drop-Down Form Field to String for use in VBA formula

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a Word 2010 template. I have a button at the top to automatically save the Word doc as a pdf with the (almost) correct name, in the correct directory, and open the doc.

I also have a Drop-Down Form Field to select the month.

[image]

The code for the button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Convert_PDF
End Sub


Sub Convert_PDF()

    Dim desktoploc As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim date As String
    Dim user As String
    Dim mypath As String

    desktoploc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    filename = "Installs Team Metrics"
    user = VBA.Environ("USERNAME")
    mypath = desktoploc & "\Metrics\" & filename & " - " & date & " - " & user

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        mypath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

This outputs the file to C:\Users[username]\Desktop\Metrics\Installs Team Metrics - [Month] - [username].pdf

How do I get what is selected in the dropdown box to the string "date".

Comment: can you add screen shot of your doc presenting type of combo-box you use?

Comment: couldnt add it in the post, not enough rep. http://i.imgur.com/hIA7DkH.png

you get it by going to developer tab->Controls->Legacy Tools->Drop-Down Form Field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a content control rather than a legacy field, so you would need

Activedocument.Contentcontrols(i).Range.Text

Where i is the index no. of the control (the first one in the document is 1, etc.)

So either you need to know the number, or you need to use the title or tag of the control (or something else) to identify the control. In the case of content controls, you then have to iterate the collection to find it, e.g.

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
For Each cc in ActiveDocument.ContentControls
  If cc.Tag = "mytag" Then
    strDate = cc.Range.Text
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Be careful how you title/tag your controls. Word does not enforce uniqueness of either titles or tags.

Another way to do this would be to create a Custom XML Part with a "Date" element and connect your control to it using xPath. Then you can retrieve the value directly from the Custom XML Part and you don't need to know anything about the control itself. But I think in a simple form that adds complications that you can do without.

Comment: thanks bibadiak, I'll give that a try and let you know how it turns out

Comment: Would I need to put that within its own sub? How exactly would I structure that? please keep in mind, Im a total n00b at VBA...

Comment: No, you can put the code in your existing routine - optionally you can move the Dim to the top of your routine, and you would need to Dim "strDate" or change it to "date" to fit your existing code. Ideally, you would also deal with the case where you do not find the appropriate tag, and so on.